# Accessible ZK Datebox

Tags: html, css, accessibility, zk

The ZK datebox component generates HTML code like this (see https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/input/date_and_time_picker)

```
<span id="cJ8Pp" class="z-datebox">
  <input id="cJ8Pp-real" class="z-datebox-input" autocomplete="off" value="2016.12.23." type="text" size="12">
    <a id="cJ8Pp-btn" class="z-datebox-button">
      <i class="z-datebox-icon z-icon-calendar"></i>
    </a>
    <div id="cJ8Pp-pp" style="display:none"></div>
</span>
```

The `<i>` tag is styled with the following CSS to display a calendar icon:

```
.z-icon-calendar:before {
    content: "\f073";
}
```

This kind of solutions are applied also in other ZK components like paging icons, etc.

I have to make accessibility approvements on our pages. I see that is a "mission impossible", because ZK generates funny things like `<div>` inside `<span>` or this Unicode icon trick. But perhaps I can do some improvements.

As the first idea I put an "alt" attribute to the `<a>` tag because it is a command component without textual representation. Then I realised that it is invalid HTML, "alt" should be set on an `<img>` tag inside `<a>`. But there is no valid place in my situation for the "alt" attribute.

What should I do (apart from choosing an other framework)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do or what's your expected html output?
You don't need to choose another framework, ZK is very flexible with alternating components, of course if you know how to do it.

Comment: Making applications accessible can be very easy but can feel daunting if you haven't done it before.  Are you familiar with the ARIA attributes in html5?  In your example, trying to add 'alt' to an anchor tag, which you noted is not valid html, instead you would use aria-label.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#state_prop_def_header for other ARIA attributes.  I teach classes on accessibility but can't do it in this comment section.  Research WCAG 2.0 (web content accessibility guidelines).  There are a lot of simple things you can do to improve accessibility.

Comment: @slugolicious: Thank you for your comment, it solves my problem. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it as a solution!